# How to Validate a file which user send by Presigned URl to S3 Bucket during upload file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

When user send a file or any data by Presigned URL to S3 Bucket. In between no restriction. So User Can send anything by Presigned URL to S3 Bucket.
But I want check data between Presigned URL and S3 Bucket which data user send.

I am using serverless framework.
please help me, Thanks in Advance.

*My lambda function code here*

```
module.exports.uploadLarge = async (event) => {
    console.log({ event })
    try {
        const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
        console.log({ body })
        const action = body.action;
        const type = body.type;
        const key = body.key;
        const params = {
            Bucket: BucketName,
            Key: key,
            // ContentType: type,
            Expires: 10000,
        }
        if (action === "putObject") {
            params.ContentType = type;
            // params.Expires = 20000
        }
        console.log({ params })
        // const url = S3.getSignedUrlPromise(action, params);
        const u = S3.getSignedUrl(action, params);
        console.log({ u });
        // console.log({ url });
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({ u }),
            headers: {
                // "Content-Type": "application/json"
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> But I want check data between Presigned URL and S3 Bucket which data user send.

Its not possible with your current design. You can only perform a check after the user have uploaded the file. For example, setup an S3 trigger for `PutObject` event which will trigger a lambda function to verify the file. Otherwise, you have to change your architecture, and put some proxy between users and S3. For example, Apigateway, or CloudFront, or custom application.

Comment: okay, but how to detect a file validation ? it is possible to detect a file when user send data or file (when trigger putObject) ? and see my code (above). I am beginner so please help me.

Comment: @hydraCode For the exact validation code in your case, please make new question, rather than changing your original issue to a new issue. My answer addresses the original question you posted.

Comment: Okay, I make new Question.